# Export configurable products with associated simples in one csv

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, csv, importexport

I'm not quite sure how this is done. I want to export a csv with configurable products along with the associated products. Then I would like to import them over on another magento install. How is this done? and is there a way around getting an extension? I have already tried 
http://www.magelynx.com/checkout/cart/configure/id/1166/
but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can find the information you need in Magento's user manual:

There should be no need for any 3rd party modules to achieve such.

- http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/dataflow.html?Highlight=dataflow

Comment: Link is 404ing, which is why SE asks that you give the answer rather than just a link.

Comment: Link works fine for me. http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/data-transfer-manage.html it's official Magento document don't think copy/pasta to SE serves much purpose when there's plenty of archives like way back machine, etc. to reference on dead links.

Comment: It only works now because it was edited after my comment. The advice from Stack overflow's [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page suggest that "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline"

Comment: Way back machine works just as well FYI https://web.archive.org/web/20160506154048/http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/store-operations/dataflow.html ...and yes i'm familar with the StackOverflows guidelines.